# Laravel can't two tables connected with each other by foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, constraints

I have two tables.

```
tableone: id, tabletwo_id
tabletwo: id, tableone_id
```

structure is something like that. they are connected using foreign key, but now I can't delete these tables at all. I mean laravel rollback doesn't work, tableone expects tabletwo to be deleted first and vice versa. So what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be firstly delete foregin key constrant, then  table.

```
Schema::table('tabletwo', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->dropForeign('tabletwo_table_one_id_foreign');
});

Schema::drop('tabletwo');
```

Comment: What does "Also you use" mean? what are these two?